# Change Button Text on Navbar in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

I am trying to customize button through page. I mean when I change page I would like to change name of navbar button when ı change route.But when I change location it's not showing me correct button without refresh page. How could I fix it.

`Navbar.js`

```
function StyledNavbar() {
    const checkPath = (pathname) => {

        if (pathname === '/details') {
            return (<div>
               <Link to='/' style={{marginRight:'10px'}}><button>Home</button></Link>
               <Link to='/favorites'><button>Favorites</button></Link>
            </div>)
       }
        else if (pathname === '/favorites') {
            return (<Link to='/'><button>Home</button></Link>)

       }
        else if (pathname === '/') {
            return (<Link to='/favorites'><button>Favorites</button></Link>)
       }
   }
   useEffect(checkPath,[window.location.pathname])...}
```

`App.js`

```
function App() {
    return(
        <Router>
            
    <Navbar/>
        <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'>
                                     <Home/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/favorites'>
                        <Favorites/>
                    </Route>
                {/* <Route path='/details/:id'> */}
                <Route path='/details'>
                        <Details/>
                    </Route>
     </Switch>
        </Router>
    )...}
```

Comment: its working when ı refresh page after routing But ı do not understand why its not working when it route

Comment: Its probably because your Navbar isnt inside of your switch.

Comment: As you can see, you can't format code in a comment. Please post an answer to show the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

[image: App.js]

If I do like that its solving but ı need to use Navbar inside of Each Route Tag